# IntelliJ doesn't produce any compiled file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-13

In my my "Project compiler output" I got a path but the directory doesn't even exist and I ran my code multiple time, I tried "Make" "Make module" "Compile class" and the program run as expected inside of **Intellij** but it doesn't produce any executable.

Maybe it is because it's a long loop that runs for hours and I stop it every time with `Alt+F2` but how to **produce the executable** without having **IntelliJ** to actually **execute** it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S
```

And then select `Artifacts` and add `JAR`.

You can also use maven for building, Intellij handles it very well.